# Use Sentry with Beego

Tags: go, sentry, beego

I've been using [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)  in my Python projects, recently I started a project with Go and Beego framework and I need to configure [Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/) for bug reports in my project. But after reading Beego documentation I couldn't find a proper way to do it. Please help me if you implemented this before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of reading BeeGo and Sentry codes I figured out how to implement this:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"

    "github.com/astaxie/beego"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/context"
    "github.com/astaxie/beego/logs"
    "github.com/getsentry/raven-go"
)

func init() {
    raven.SetDSN(beego.AppConfig.String("SentryDSN"))

    if !beego.BConfig.RecoverPanic {
        beego.BConfig.RecoverFunc = recoverPanic
    }
}

func recoverPanic(ctx *context.Context) {
    if err := recover(); err != nil {
        if err == beego.ErrAbort {
            return
        }
        if !beego.BConfig.RecoverPanic {
            errStr := fmt.Sprint(err)
            packet := raven.NewPacket(errStr, raven.NewException(errors.New(errStr), raven.NewStacktrace(2, 3, nil)), raven.NewHttp(ctx.Request))
            raven.Capture(packet, nil)
            ctx.ResponseWriter.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }

        //if beego.BConfig.EnableErrorsShow {
        //  if _, ok := beego.ErrorMaps[fmt.Sprint(err)]; ok {
        //      exception(fmt.Sprint(err), ctx)
        //      return
        //  }
        //}
        var stack string
        logs.Critical("the request url is ", ctx.Input.URL())
        logs.Critical("Handler crashed with error", err)
        for i := 1; ; i++ {
            _, file, line, ok := runtime.Caller(i)
            if !ok {
                break
            }
            logs.Critical(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", file, line))
            stack = stack + fmt.Sprintln(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", file, line))
        }
        //if beego.BConfig.RunMode == beego.DEV && beego.BConfig.EnableErrorsRender {
        //  showErr(err, ctx, stack)
        //}

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This might be a simple solution, without disabling beego original recover function:

```
func initRecover() {
    originRecover := beego.BConfig.RecoverFunc
    beego.BConfig.RecoverFunc = func(ctx *context.Context) {
        defer originRecover(ctx)
        if err := recover(); err != nil {
            //*** your reporting code here. ***
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```